# How to assign a name to an object when the name is stored in a different vector

Tags: r

Given these two objects:

```
v <- "new.name"

w <- 1:10
```

How can I tell `R` to rename w as new.name, so I can have this

```
  > new.name
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `new.name <- w; rm(w)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
assign(v, w)
new.name
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But it is considered a very bad practice in R, so read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-assign-bad) first