# Create a stack of n subset data frames from a single data frame based on date column

Tags: r

I need to create a bunch of subset data frames out of a single big `df`, based on a date column (e.g. - "Aug 2015" in month-Year format). It should be something similar to the subset function, except that the count of subset dfs to be formed should change dynamically depending upon the available values on date column

All the subsets data frames need to have similar structure, such that the date column value will be one and same for each and every subset `df`.

Suppose, If my big `df` currently has last 10 months of data, I need 10 subset data frames now, and 11 dfs if i run the same command next month (with 11 months of base data).

I have tried something like below. but after each  iteration, the subset `subdf_i` is getting overwritten. Thus, I am getting only one subset df atlast, which is having the last value of month column in it.

I thought that would be created as 45 subset dfs like `subdf_1`, `subdf_2`,... and `subdf_45` for all the 45 unique values of month column correspondingly.

```
uniqmnth <- unique(df$mnth)

for (i in 1:length(uniqmnth)){

    subdf_i <- subset(df, mnth == uniqmnth[i])

    i==i+1

}
```

I hope there should be some option in the subset function or any looping might do. I am a beginner in R, not sure how to arrive at this.

Comment: What have you already tried? Does `split()` cover your needs? Otherwise, look into the dplyr package.

Comment: @Bala Please [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to ask a reproducible example.

Comment: The fact that you are using RStudio has nothing to do here. If you seeking for help, you should first make an effort and read the site policy regarding how to ask a question as already pointed above.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for the suggestions about reproducible example. I will keep in mind, going forward.

Comment: If you are using `for` loop, you may need `assign` to create new object names in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the perfect solution for this might be use of assign() for the iterating variable i, to get appended in the names of each of the 45 subsets. Thanks for the note from my friend. Here is the solution to avoid the subset data frame being overwritten each run of the loop.

```
uniqmnth <- unique(df$mnth)

for (i in 1:length(uniqmnth)){
  assign(paste("subdf_",i,sep=""), subset(df, mnth == uniqmnth[i])) i==i+1 
}
```

Comment: You don't need `i=i+1`

Comment: I would recommend avoid using `assign` in order to create objects in your global environment take a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-assign-bad)

Comment: As @DavidArenburg it is better not to create lots of objects in the global environment.