# Create a variable using loop and assign

Tags: r, loops, assign

If I have a data set "c" and one variable "x" inside.

The x variable only has two observation is 5 and 6.

I want to assign two variable `c1`, `c2` for `c$x[1]` and `c$x[2]`

I tried to use the function below, but it does not work.

```
rf<-function(){
    for(i in 1:2)
assign(paste("c", i,sep=""),paste("c$x[",i, "]" ,sep="")])}
```

How could I revise the syntax to get the results?

Comment: Even better: don't use `assign` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-assign-bad)

Comment: this sounds like an xy-problem...

Comment: What is "assing"?  I've never used that method before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use paste in the second argument for assign.

`assign(paste("c", i,sep=""),c$x[i]))` will work.