# Make column name the variable name and assign the value of the column to that variable

Tags: r, variables, assign, names

Lets take the following DF

```
> df <- data.frame(var1=5,var2=6,var3=7)
> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    5    6    7
>
```

i now want to automatically have three variables been "created" and added to the global environement with their respective values, like so:

```
var1 <- 5
var2 <- 6
var3 <- 7
```

## How can i do it?

Thank you in advance.
André

Comment: Global variables are very very  risky idea, could you elaborate on what is your goal in this attempt

Comment: i have found a rather complex function on the web that can evaluate my survey. I think by doing the above i can use it to my needs without having to  dig deep and understand it fully. Its more or less a test and if it works i saved alot of time. I know its a ugly thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should ask yourself if there is no other way than assigning global variables, see [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-assign-bad) for some discussions about that topic.
If you really want to do it that way, you could do

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    assign(colnames(df)[i], df[,i])
}
```

However, I would encourage you to find a different solution than assigning variables.

Comment: is there a way to do it with lapply? cant make it work: lapply(df, function(x) assign(names(x), x))

Comment: thanks anyways. It worked i could get the scores and everything is perfect :-)