# Store multiple vectors in a list using for-loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector

I'm new to R. I have multiple vectors which I want to store in a list in a for loop. I've tried using [], [[]] and () and I am getting an error stating that dateRange not found. Can you please help and fix my code?

```
dateRange1 <- c('2015-01','2015-12')
dateRange2 <- c('2016-01','2016-12')
ind <- list()

for (a in 1:2) {
  ind[a] <- dateRange(a)
 }

ind
```

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: It is not very clear, do you need smth like this `dateRange = list(c('2015-01','2015-12'), c('2016-01','2016-12'))` ?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not clear. But I want to store all the dateRange to the list called "ind" so when I access the ind[[1]] it will display the values of dateRange1 and ind[[2]] it will display the values in dateRange2. Hope this make sense.

Comment: How you get the multiple vectors? During that process you can generate your list.

Comment: `ind = list(c('2015-01','2015-12'), c('2016-01','2016-12'))`. and now `ind[[1]]` gives you your first range. if you need to append to the `ind` list, then just do `ind <- append(ind, list(c('2017-05','2016-12')))`

Comment: @AlexNevsky I suppose OP has many more such vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want that, use `get()` or `mget()`

```
ind <- mget(paste0("dateRange", 1:2))
```

Normaly you get such a bunch of vectors if you used `assign()` somewhere before. That is the point where you have to restructure your process of data generation. (Normaly the use of `assign()` is not a good idea. "If the question is: *use `assign()`?* the answer almost is: **no**").
[Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This mget fucnction would this apply also if I have several input$daterange in the dateRangeInput in SHiny R/ Just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an object called `dateRange`. To do what you're trying to need to use `eval` and `parse`. Set `a <- 1` then run pieces individually to see what they do. Check to see what `paste0("dateRange", a)` does, then `parse(text = paste0("dateRange", a))`, then `eval(parse(text = paste0("dateRange", a)))`.

```
dateRange1 <- c('2015-01','2015-12')
dateRange2 <- c('2016-01','2016-12')
ind <- list()

for (a in 1:2) {
  ind[[a]] <- eval(parse(text = paste0("dateRange", a)))
}

ind
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. This is what I am looking for. Appreciate your time.