# How can I include variables in a dataframe name in R?

Tags: r

I am interested in something like this:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    df[i]<-function(x,y,i)
}
```

Where I would like the output to be 10 different dataframes with names df1, df2, df3, etc.

I know you can include variables in a dataframe column name using:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    df[,paste0(i)]<-function(x,y,i)
}
```

But I would like 10 separate dataframes, not 1 dataframe with 10 appropriately named columns.

Comment: Generally having a bunch of different variables lying around in the global namespace with similar names and data structures just makes things more difficult later to work with them. In the long run you'll probably be happier keeping such related items in a named list and just use `lapply()` or `Map()` to create that list. This is a much more R-like way to work with data. Better to [avoid assign()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html). Here, I create 10 vectors called `df1`, `df2`, etc., and assign them values from a function (e.g., `sqrt`).

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), sqrt(i))
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to create a data frame with a column that has a dynamic name, you could use this:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), setNames(data.frame(1:5), LETTERS[i]))
}
```

Here, I used `LETTERS` to name my columns, but you can use whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks @Lyngbakr! What if I wanted to assign my function output to a specific column within the dataframe? Ex. `assign(paste("df", i, sep = "")[[InfoTable$Name[i]]], sqrt(i))` The syntax isn't quite right but I'm not sure where to use either the [[]] or the $ operator

Comment: Like this? `assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), data.frame(Stuff = 1:5))` This adds it to a column named `Stuff`.