# Unexpected error message while joining data.table with rbindlist() using mget()

Tags: r, data.table

While preparing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47670107/3817004), I've got the error message

> Error: value for ‘spine_hlfs’ not found

from running

```
setDT(giraffe)[rbindlist(mget(df_names), idcol = "df.name"), on = "runkey", project := df.name][]
```

while

```
df_list <- mget(df_names)
setDT(giraffe)[rbindlist(df_list, idcol = "df.name"), on = "runkey", project := df.name][]
```

works as expected.

Before reporting an issue on github, I want to verify with the community that this indeed is a bug or if there is a simple explanation for the error message which I'm unaware of.

#### Reproducible example

```
set.seed(123L)
giraffe <- data.frame(runkey = 1:500,
                      X2 = sample.int(99L, 500L, TRUE),
                      X3 = sample.int(99L, 500L, TRUE),
                      X4 = sample.int(99L, 500L, TRUE),
                      project = "",
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
spine_hlfs <- data.frame(runkey = c(1L, 498L, 5L))
ir_dia     <- data.frame(runkey = c(3L, 499L, 47L, 327L))
df_names <- c("spine_hlfs", "ir_dia")
library(data.table)

# this creates the error message
setDT(giraffe)[rbindlist(mget(df_names), idcol = "df.name"), on = "runkey", project := df.name][]
## Error: value for ‘spine_hlfs’ not found

# this works as expected
df_list <- mget(df_names)
setDT(giraffe)[rbindlist(df_list, idcol = "df.name"), on = "runkey", project := df.name][]
```

Comment: It's just too many nested environments. Try `mget(df_names, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically because (unlike `get`) `mget` has `inherits = FALSE` as default. Hence it only looks in the local environment. Changing to `mget(df_names, inherits = TRUE)` (or, if you want to be explicit to `mget(df_names, envir = .GlobalEnv)`) should fix this.

[This was independently reported by @Arun on GH a while ago](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1712) and he intends to change the default behavior of `mget` (while used within a `data.table`) to be consistent with `get` in the future, so stay tuned.