# Referring to an object within a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm sure there is an easy answer. I have a loop, where for each iteration, I create a new vector to store the results. I do this by pasting a name together and then assigning that name to an empty vector.

```
for (i in seq(1, 50)) {

    current_iteration = i

    x = paste0("resultsVec", current_iteration)

    assign(x, rep(NA, 43))

    paste0("resultsVec", i)

    for (j in seq(1, 100))
    {
        resultsVeci[j] = j * j # <- problem here 
    }


}
```

However, you obviously can't refer to 'resultsVeci' - so how to I refer to the iteration specific vector each loop?

If you do `paste0("resultsVec", i)`, where i=2 for example, it returns a string `"resultsVec2"`, rather than the object `resultsVec2`. How do I refer to the object rather than the string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It really isn't a good idea to use `get()` and `assign()` with most R code. ([Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)). Better to just use a list. A simple `lapply` would work here.

```
resultsVec<-lapply(1:50, function(i) (1:100)*(1:100))
```

and then you can get the values with `reusltsVec[[1]]`, `resultsVec[[2]]`, etc