# How to get a value from vector and assign it as a name of new dataframe

Tags: r

IN R
I have a vector of NAME:

```
[1] "ALKR50SV" "AMKR71SV" "AOKR71SV" "AZKR52SV" "BFKR70SV" "BJKR61SV" "BUKR6HSV" 
    "CDKR61SV" "CFKR31SV"
```

I want to use them as a name for each new dataframe

Like dataframe of ALKR50SV, dataframe of ALKR50SV ......

for loop like:

```
NAME[i] <- data1
```

will cause problem.

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: you want to use these values as dataframe names ?

Comment: Might be easier to create a named list of dataframes using the vector for the list names.

Comment: This isn't how we do things in R, it will just lead to problems later on. Put the data frames in a single object, a list, and then the list items can have names. e.g. `setNames(my_list_of_dfs, NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @joran and @neilfws said, best to work with a `list` of `data.frame`s.
For example, consider the following list of three `data.frame`s

```
lst <- lapply(1:3, function(x) as.data.frame(matrix(sample(20), ncol = 4)));
```

You can name `list` elements

```
names(lst) <- c("ALKR50SV", "AMKR71SV", "AOKR71SV");
```

and operate on `list` elements using `lapply`, e.g.

```
lapply(lst, dim);
#$ALKR50SV
#[1] 5 4
#
#$AMKR71SV
#[1] 5 4
#
#$AOKR71SV
#[1] 5 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `assign`:

```
numbers <- c('one', 'two', 'three')
for (i in 1:3) {
    assign(nms[i], i)
}
one # 1
two # 2
three # 3
```

But as others have commented, it is most likely better to put your dataframes into a named list.

Comment: [Why is using assign a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)

Comment: Using assign is a bad idea, but it's not a bad answer to the question. The downvote is not appropriate.

Comment: @mikeck I didn't downvote; but I don't agree with your comment. The use of `assign` should not be promoted. Especially not in an answer.

Comment: @maurits, I was making a general statement and did not mean to suggest you specifically were the one who downvoted. Perhaps I'm a bit more conservative in using downvotes; it's a technically correct answer that does not break or abuse standard functionality of R, so I don't think it deserves a downvote. But I agree that using `assign` should not be promoted, so I wouldn't upvote it either :)