# appending new value in loop using `get` function

Tags: r, loops

I need to make loop that assigns new values to certain vectors based on vector of vectors names. Overall, it can be easily done just by using `assign`. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(11)
my_future_vectors=c("vec1","vec2","vec3")
for (i in 1:length(my_future_vectors)){assign(my_future_vectors[i],runif(3,0:1))}
```

The problem with `assign` is that whenever I need to add new values to those vectors it overwrites them. If I want add `1` and I do:

```
assign(my_future_vectors[1],1)
```

Than:

```
> vec1
[1] 1
```

This is understandable, but what works for me is `vec1[length(vec1)+1]=1`, which gives output:

```
> vec1
[1] 0.2772497942 1.0000000000 0.0005183129 1.0000000000
```

Problem arises whenever i try to use function `get` to address certain vector:

```
get(my_future_vectors[1])[length(my_future_vectors[1])+1]=1
```

I get an error:

```
Error in get(my_future_vectors[1])[length(my_future_vectors[1])] = 1 : 
  could not find function "get<-
```

So I understand that `get` doesnt work this way, so I have no idea how make a loop like that. Please provide solution or workaround to avoid this error. Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You need a close parentheses. Read the error, it is looking for a function called "get<-", because you didn't type the final parentheses of get()

Comment: Why are you using `get()/assign()` at all here? Rather than have a vector of character names of vectors, why not keep all your values in a named list? This will make things much easier to work with in R.

Comment: More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad

Comment: The use of `get`/`assign` is almost always able to be replaced with (optionally-named) lists or similar constructs, and doing so provides performance gains and promotes a much-more scalable way of thinking about the process as a whole.

Comment: Besides not using get/assign, you should also not dynamically grow vectors in R. For similar hints about good R programming practice, maybe read the R Inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will make research about lists in R and try to rewrite my current code. Btw, why dynamically growing vectors is wrong in R? It is crucial to huge part of my work...

Comment: See [Chapter 2](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).