# What's the reason that I should use "assign()"?

Tags: r

I already know that if I assign variable in for loop, I should use `assign()` like this

```
for(i in 1:6) { #-- Create objects  'r.1', 'r.2', ... 'r.6' --
   nam <- paste("r", i, sep = ".")
   assign(nam, 1:i)
}
```

But I wonder what fundamentally difference is between `<-` and `assign()`

I read documentation, and I know that `assign()` access the environment.

It is the only difference I know.

Comment: Ideally you should avoid using `assign`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Comment: The only good time to use `assign` is when you're doing things you shouldn't be doing.  Take your example ... you should be using a named list for that.

Comment: I read that. For data analysis(like `lm()`) and FP, I had better make named list, not multiple variable right?

Comment: For things like `lm`, structures like `data.frame` exist for precisely this purpose

Comment: Don't use assign. Don't make objects `r.1`, `r.2`, `r.3`, ... make a list named `r` and you can use `r[[1]]`, `r[[2]]`, `r[[3]]`, `r[[some_variable]]`. You can assign names to the list or use indices. In addition to Ronak's link, I'd recommend [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for the discussion of why sequentially named variables are hard to work with and how `list`s are a great alternative.

Comment: As for the difference, try doing what you're doing without `assign` and see that it doesn't work. If you do `nam <- "r.1"` and then `nam <- 1`, then `nam` is `1` and `r.1` is still nothing.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`: 

*The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign
function.*
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)

Comment: The "only difference [you] know" is actually a very important difference. `assign` gives you precise control where you assign into. That can be important for some advanced stuff. As a beginner, you don't need `assign` and shouldn't use it.