# Looping through dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame "MYdata" and want to split this up to create three new datasets "test_1", "test_2" and "test_3". The first one "test_1" should contain only the first column from "MYdata", the second dataset should only contain the second column and so on. I am trying this:

```
for (i in 1:3)
{
test_[i] <- MYdata[i]
}
```

But I get the following error message: "*Error in test_[i] <- MYdata[i] : object 'test_' not found*"

Any ideas?

Comment: `[` is for indexing an existing object - not for creating new object names. BTW: you should learn using lists (but then eventually there is no need to construct new objects because a dataframe is a special kind of list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assign` to include a value in an object with name specified by `paste0`.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("test_", i), MYdata[i])
}
```

Each column will be a new data frame.

Comment: `library("fortunes");
fortune(236)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad?s=6|45.4089

Comment: Thanks Bruno. That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jogo. I'm new on R and have learned a lot with this kind of tips. I will need to study this better to really understand.

Comment: @SAS_converted_to_R if the answer is correct, mark it as the answer for the question, please :)

Comment: Sorry this was my first post. I believe I have marked it now. Thanks and sorry again. :)