# Filter data, remove entire dataframe

Tags: r

My data is like this:

```
X1e  X2e  X3e  X4e
360    0    0    0
360    0    0    0
260    0    0    0
0      0    0    0
0      0    0    0
0      0    0    0
90     0    0    0
360    0  360    0
360    0  360  260
```

I want to remove the  X1e X4e columns between 0 and 270, did not remove 0 row

```
for (i in c(1,4)){
  e <- assign(paste("X",i, "e",sep = ""),i)
  dat <- dat[with(dat, !((e>0)&(e<270))), ] 
}
```

This removes all my dat and my dat became empty. Where is my problem?

Comment: I only want to remove the row  ( 260  0  0  0)  ,(90 0 0 0) and row (360 0 360  260)  , but it remove  all the line ,I think my code is right  Is there a problem with my R enviroment , but I  reinstall my R from 3.5.1 to 3.4.4  the problem still  remain

Comment: *"Where is my problem?"* You're not using `assign` correctly, and in fact, you should avoid using `assign` altogether! See [Why is using assign bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Comment: Your code is definitiely not right. In your loop the variable `e` is `1` in the first iteration. Therefore all the rows get deletetd, because `1>0 & 1<270` is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Base R Solution:

```
dat[!(dat$X1e>0 & dat$X1e<270) & !(dat$X4e>0 & dat$X4e<270),]
```

**OR**

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from dat where X1e not between 1 AND 270 AND X4e not between 1 AND 270")
```

Output:

```
   X1e X2e X3e X4e
1 360   0   0   0
2 360   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0
6 360   0 360   0
```

Comment: “select * from dat where X2e not between 0 AND 360 AND X3e not between 0 AND 360"

Answer (score 2):

Create the column names of interest

```
cidx <- paste0("X", c(1, 4), "e")
```

Perform the logical operations on each column

```
test <- !(df[,cidx] > 0 & df[,cidx] < 270)
```

Sum (logical 'and') across rows to find those where all columns are `TRUE`

```
ridx <- rowSums(test) == length(cidx)
```

Subset the original data.frame

```
df[ridx,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
 df<-read.table(text="X1e  X2e  X3e  X4e
 360    0    0    0
            360    0    0    0
            260    0    0    0
            0      0    0    0
            0      0    0    0
            0      0    0    0
            90     0    0    0
            360    0  360    0
            360    0  360  260",header=T)
 df%>%
   filter_at(vars(X1e,X4e), all_vars(.<=0 | .>270))
  X1e X2e X3e X4e
1 360   0   0   0
2 360   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0
6 360   0 360   0
```

Comment: but is not the all_vars(.<=0 | .>270)  is the  [X1e,X4e] (.<=0 | .>270) and [X2e, X3e](.<=0 | .>=360).

Comment: 'all_vars` there used only for `vars(X1e,X4e)`

Comment: I had an error " Error in all_vars(. = 0 | . >= 270) : unused argument (. = 0 | . >= 270)"

Comment: Can I use this style:   filter_at(vars(a,h), all_vars(((a+h)<3.8)&((a+h)>0)))

Comment: a and h is two columns date

Comment: And if I want to delete row   X1e is NA and X2e is not NA . I can use this

Comment: for last one `df%>%
 filter_at(vars(X1e,X4e), all_vars(.<=0 | .>270))%>%
  filter(is.na(X1e) & !is.na(X2e))`

Comment: And if I want to delete row   a is NA and h is not NA . I can use this  line:  filter_at(vars(a,h), all_vars(((a=NA)&(h!=NA))|((a!=NA)&(h=NA))))

Comment: filter((is.na(a) & !is.na(h))|(!is.na(a) & is.na(h)))  this  delete all my data is there to filter two step?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution.
I usually don't like `subset` because it uses non standard evaluation and it is slow but here it goes.

```
subset(df, (X1e <= 0 | X1e >= 270) & (X4e <= 0 | X4e >= 270))
#  X1e X2e X3e X4e
#1 360   0   0   0
#2 360   0   0   0
#4   0   0   0   0
#5   0   0   0   0
#6   0   0   0   0
#8 360   0 360   0
```