# Need to use a value which name is generated automatically

Tags: r

I`m using

```
assign( paste("ship", b, sep = ""),c())
```

as a vector where i want to save the coordinates of certain elements of a matrix.

Now i want to use the vector, as a example the first vector it´s named ship1 and i want to add elements to that vector but I can`t use append and paste("ship", b, sep = "") because I get this error

```
Error in paste("barco", b, sep = "") <- append(paste("barco", b, sep = ""),  : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

My question is: How can I use my vector without using specifically ship1 thus been able to use a generic method to fill all other "ship b" vectors

Comment: Please take a look at [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) and then edit your question to provide a [reproducible code example including sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You need `get`.

```
b = 1
VName = paste("ship", b, sep = "")
assign(VName,c())
assign(VName, append(get(VName), 1:3))
get(VName)
[1] 1 2 3
```

But see @MauritsEvers comment about using `assign`

Comment: You might want to use paste0() since it is a bit faster.

Comment: thanks for the help but i don´t think I get it right. My problem is that i don´t know hot to use a generic form to use the vector that I want based only in the b of it´s name