# R: error when trying a loop with dplyr filter function

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

Trying to simplify and make my code reproducible, I have the following loop code which aims to subset a data frame and store every subsetting in a new variable:

```
types <- c("POINT", "NONPOINT", "ON-ROAD", "NON-ROAD")

for (i in seq_along(types)) {
   paste("type", types[i], sep = "") <- filter(NEI$Emissions, NEI$type == types[i])
}
```

I expected my loop to store every subsetting (4 subsettings) in a new variable called "type" and the corresponding string. Instead of it, I get the following error:

> "Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

I've already tried to modify the class of type coercing it to be a string through `as.character(types)` but got no success.

Edit: the output of `head(NEI)` is the following:

```
   fips      SCC  Pollutant Emissions  type year
4  09001 10100401  PM25-PRI    15.714 POINT 1999
8  09001 10100404  PM25-PRI   234.178 POINT 1999
12 09001 10100501  PM25-PRI     0.128 POINT 1999
16 09001 10200401  PM25-PRI     2.036 POINT 1999
20 09001 10200504  PM25-PRI     0.388 POINT 1999
24 09001 10200602  PM25-PRI     1.490 POINT 1999
```

Comment: Mostly you should get what you want by doing `split(NEI$Emissions, NEI$type)`

Comment: can you add the output from `dput(head(data))` so we can help more easily?

Comment: just done, chek my edit. @RAB

Comment: I guess what you intend to achieve requires **assign**

Comment: @RonakShah If I did that I would get back the Emissions column only, and I need the full dataframe subsetted (All variables of the original data frame)

Comment: @Mauro then do `split(NEI, NEI$type)`

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I've checked it out and it works, it's a nice alternative resource. It would be great anyway if I could find out the error in my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
types <- c("POINT", "NONPOINT", "ON-ROAD", "NON-ROAD")

for (i in types) {
  assign(paste0("type", i), filter(NEI, NEI$type == i))
}
```

This will give you 4 dataframes based on `types`

Trying this on `mtcars` dataset

```
cyl <- unique(mtcars$cyl)

for (i in cyl) {
  assign(paste0("type", i), filter(mtcars, mtcars$cyl == i))
}

type6
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

and similarly other dataframes.

The reason why your solution does not work is because you are trying to assign values to characters which can be reproduced by doing

```
paste0("type", types[1]) <- filter(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl == 4)
```

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

However, [using `assign` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad), as mentioned in comments you can use `split` which would give you list of dataframes.

```
new_data <- split(NEI, NEI$type)
```

and then access them by doing `new_data[[1]]`, `new_data[[2]]` and so on.