# R Create and Invoke Dynamic Variable Name

Tags: r, variables, dynamic

I would like to generate dynamic (with an index number from the loop) and invoke it later like below:

```
for (i in seq(1,10)) {
 p_i <- i^2 #here _i is a dynamic value which is equate to the current i value
 d_i <- (p_i-20)*15 # here _i for both d_i and p_i are all dynamic
 }
```

Thank you very much for your expertise

Comment: You don't need a loop. `i <- 1:10; p <- i^2; d <- (p-20)*15` will give you all results in a vector and you only need to subset this vector to extract its elements.

Comment: @RLave Please do not even mention that function to newbies. They do not need to know it exists.

Comment: my case is a much more complicated than the example i put here, could you please give more details how to achieve creating and invoking it dynamically?

Comment: @EastLiu `myvector <- numeric(10); for (i in 1:10) {...; myvector[[i]] <- ...}` Use a list if your data cannot be stored in a vector.

Comment: @Roland. I think it is better to explain why `assign` is the worst solution and why we need to use a structure that is made to avoid artifical indexes in the environment.

Comment: Here why `assign` would be bad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad

Comment: @Clemsang This makes an assumption about readers that unfortunately often is not valid. I suspect that OP is happily using your `assign` code right now. The warning is ignored too often.

Comment: @Roland I does not use R very often, so some conceptions are quite hard for me to follow, but i really appreciate it all your efforts and kind reminders. I really do, the world need people like you guys to make it move on and towards better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that works but I would not use as it is not a good practice to recreate an artificial structure, use vectors or lists instead.

```
for (i in seq(1,10)) {
  assign(paste0("p_", i), i^2)
  assign(paste0("d_", i), (get(paste0("p_", i))-20)*15)
}
```

I would use the vectorized solution using index to access what you want :

```
p <- (1:10)^2
d <- (p-20)*15
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want. Thank yo very much.

Comment: Please consider reading `RLave` comment and avoid using `assign` in your code