# How to remove file name extensions from the global environment

Tags: r

With the code below, I have imported all `.txt` files from working directory.

```
temp=list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) { assign(temp[i], read.delim(temp[i]))
```

But all of them came with `.txt` extension like this. [image: screenshot]

How can I remove all `.txt` extensions from data names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the variables in your `for` loop itself

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {assign(sub(".txt$", "", temp[i]), read.delim(temp[i]))}
```

---

Or if you have already imported the variables change their names later

```
vals <- ls(pattern = ".txt$")
for (i in vals) { assign(sub(".txt$", "", i), get(i)) }
```

and then clean up the old names

```
rm(list = vals)
```

On a side note, using assign is considered bad. Read it's potential dangers and side effects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing about assign.