# How to import and assign variables into R with mapply or any loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have a variable list called `working_dir` that consists of the name of files I want to import

```
working_dirs
$`./.\\dataset/UCI HAR Dataset/test/Inertial Signals`
[1] "body_acc_x_test.txt"  "body_acc_y_test.txt"  "body_acc_z_test.txt"  "body_gyro_x_test.txt"
[5] "body_gyro_y_test.txt" "body_gyro_z_test.txt" "total_acc_x_test.txt" "total_acc_y_test.txt"
[9] "total_acc_z_test.txt"

$`./.\\dataset/UCI HAR Dataset/train/Inertial Signals`
[1] "body_acc_x_train.txt"  "body_acc_y_train.txt"  "body_acc_z_train.txt"  "body_gyro_x_train.txt"
[5] "body_gyro_y_train.txt" "body_gyro_z_train.txt" "total_acc_x_train.txt" "total_acc_y_train.txt"
[9] "total_acc_z_train.txt"
```

I want to import each of the files with `read.table()` and name it with the name of the file. My idea is to use `mapply()` and pass each argument into `assign()` function. something like

```
mapply(assign , working_dir, read.table(working_dir , header = T))
```

However I know this syntax is incorrect. What are they ways to achieve this?

Comment: The list is called working_dirs in your R environment.

Comment: @spazznolo yes just a variable name

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) on using `assign`. Btw you can read the files in a `list` of `data.frame`s like this:   `ldf = lapply(working_dirs, function(t){read.table(t,header=TRUE)}`  then you can also name each element of `list` like: `names(ldf) = working_dirs`

Comment: @tushaR your code is not working for me. Please see the structure of the dirs above. I need a way for multiple looping; one for each list item and one for the subitems

Comment: @Omar113 the name of list elements are the folder paths?? also, which OS are you using? How did you create this list? The best way to get paths of files is using   `list.files()` `list.files(path = ,full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote as script that worked for me.

```
library(stringr)


folders <- list.dirs()
working_dirs <- lapply( folders, function(x){ list.files(x , full.names = T) })[c(5 ,7)]


for(i in 1:length(working_dirs)){
  dire <-  working_dirs[[i]]
  direnames <- str_extract(working_dirs[[i]] , pattern = "(test|train)(.*)(\\.txt)?")
  for (ii in 1:length(dire)){
    assign(direnames[ii] , read.table(dire[ii]))
  }
}
```

This will give a separate dataframe for the 18 file!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ldf=mapply(function(x,y){read.table(paste0(x,y,sep="/"),header=TRUE)},working_dir,names(working_dir))
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me, I think because the list structure is that the directories lies under the list it self. that will not make it loop

Comment: please see my answer