# Create multiple data that count for unique values of each variables using dplyr and loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some question for programming using dplyr and for loop in order to create multiple data. The code without loop works very well, but the code with for loop doesn't give me the expected result as well as error message.

Error message was like:

> "Error in UseMethod ("select_") :   no applicable method for 'select_'
>   applied to an object of class "character"

Please anyone put me on the right way.

The code below worked

```
B <- data %>% select (column1) %>% group_by (column1) %>% arrange (column1) %>% summarise (n = n ())
```

The code below did not work

```
column_list <- c ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')

for (b in column_list) {

 a <- data %>% select (b) %>% group_by (b) %>% arrange (b) %>% summarise (n = n () )
 assign (paste0(b), a)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad). Instead use lists.

We can use `_at` variations in `dplyr` which works with characters variables.

```
library(dplyr)

split_fun <- function(df, col) {
  df %>% group_by_at(col) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% arrange_at(col)
}
```

and then use `lapply`/`map` to apply it to different columns

```
purrr::map(column_list, ~split_fun(data, .))
```

This will return you a list of dataframes which can be accessed using `[[` individually if needed.

---

Using example with `mtcars`

```
df <- mtcars
column_list <- c ('cyl', 'gear', 'carb')

purrr::map(column_list, ~split_fun(df, .))

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     4    11
#2     6     7
#3     8    14

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   gear     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     3    15
#2     4    12
#3     5     5

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   carb     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     1     7
#2     2    10
#3     3     3
#4     4    10
#5     6     1
#6     8     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your code works very well. I have one more question. Could you give me additional code for assigning those table in each different data?

Comment: @SangwonSteveLee It is already there. If you assign the value `l1 <- purrr::map(column_list, ~split_fun(data, .))`. You can then use each one of them separately. `l1[[1]]`, `l1[[2]]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your kind and clear explanation. Your solution works very well.