# Turning dataframe into variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and would like to turn the values into variables.

I've tried using as.numeric(unlist...) to pull them out one by one (it's not a big list), but I'm looking for a better way.

This is my data

```
dataframe = structure(list(V1 = c(564.58, 7834.1, 134.2), file = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I'm looking to get this:

```
Red = 564.58
Blue = 7834.1
Yellow = 134.2
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need `setNames(dataframe$V1, dataframe$file)`  OR `split(dataframe$V1, dataframe$file)` ?

Comment: I can split them, but I can't assign them as individual variables (short of going through and matching them with a loop).

Comment: you can use `assign` to convert them to individual variables but usually it is recommended to keep variables in a list rather than individual ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work. Put your values `V1` in a list with `as.list`, set the names to `file` using `setNames`, and then turn the list elements into variables in the global environment using `list2env`:

```r
list2env(setNames(as.list(df$V1), df$file), .GlobalEnv)
```

Having answered, I should also mention that doing this kind of thing is frequently discouraged. Exploding vectorized data to pollute your environment with lots of variables offers very few, if any, advantages, but there are a number of disadvantages. The discussion about `assign` also applies to `list2env`. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the link to the discussion.  I've only got a very small list and need to patch this data in.