# Assign a variable name in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a new variable which will correspond to a dataframe. The function "assign" does not work because the dataframe is too complex (it uses `dplyr` functions from a parent dataframe).

Just to try out I ran the following code:

```
Fam <- paste0("Fam", seq(13,53,2))
for(i in Fam){
  i <- seq(1,5,1)
}
```

There is no error popping up but I would like to have each variable created on the environment (`Fam13`, `Fam15`, `Fam17`, etc.)

When I run my code there is no error either but no variables are created.

```
for (i in Fam){
  i <- CPS_reduced %>%
    filter(SOC_Fam == i)%>%
    select(Occupation, Share.of.population.2002, Share.of.population.2018, Share.of.population.2034, Share.2034.with.robots)
```

I have also tried to create a function to do this and then do something like

```
Fam <- function(i)
paste0("Fam",i) <- CPS_reduced %>%
filter(SOC_Fam ==i)
...

lapply(seq(13,53,2), function(i))
```

However, this gives the error that I can't assign something to `paste0`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're looking for `?assign` but see this first [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)

Comment: Use a named list instead: `df_list <- split(CPS_reduced, CPS_reduced$SOC_Fam)`.

Comment: Can you post what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to avoid creating a bunch of free floating variables in your workspace. It's much more difficult to work list. Using a named list for related objects makes things so much easier in R.

Comment: @MrFlick but you suggest that i have a list where each variable is a dataframe?