# Combining nested list items with similar names in R

Tags: r

This question is somewhat of a continuation of a previous question I asked [Combining data based on user input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773964/combining-data-based-on-user-input-in-r). It was recommended to store my data in lists rather than as individual items in the global environment. Therefore I am attempting to import all similar file types (e.g. .csv) into a list of lists. Each nested list represents one of multiple time series .csv files. This currently works using the following code:

```
ImportData <- function(mypattern,...)
{
  mypattern <- readline(prompt = "Enter File Type:")
  temp <- list.files(".", pattern=mypattern)
  myfiles <- lapply(temp, fread, skip = 1) 
  names(myfiles) <- gsub("-.*", "", temp)
  header <- c("index","DateTime", "Voltage")
  myfiles <<- lapply(myfiles, setNames, header)
}
ImportData()
```

The next step is to combine lists of time series data with similar names that represent data from the same site. After running the above function `myfiles` contains lists with names such as ASW1.csv, ASW1_10Sept.csv, ASW1_2017, as well as others with different abbreviations (e.g. CSW). My goal with the below function is to prompt the user to input a site name (e.g. ASW1) and for every list within the `myfiles` list with a name containing ASW1 to be combined and sorted by date into a new list called ASW1 within `myfiles`. Then the user can call all the data from a particular site.

```
CombineData <- function()
{
  Site <- invisible(readline(prompt = "Enter Site Name:"))
  myfiles[[Site]] <<- rbindlist(mget(apropos(Site), inherits = TRUE))
}
CombineData()
```

The issue I am having is when running `CombineData` an empty list is added to `myfiles` rather than one that contains all the data from any list with the name provided in `Site`. I can manually combine the lists:

```
ASW1 <- myfiles[c(1,2,3,4)]
ASW1 <- rbindlist(ASW1)
```

but my goal is to make this process as automated as possible. In a previous version of my code I used the following to grab everything containing a particular name `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^ASW1")))` but clearly there must be something different when working with lists.

Comment: Hi bmdanhof. How are you getting on with the answers below? `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Does the following solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)
reqdNames = names(mylist)[grepl("asw",names(mylist))]

finalDf = bind_rows(mylist[reqdNames])
```

It is possible I have misunderstood the problem. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.
Try to work with functions that require a data argument and that return the data, when the function executes.

Instead of have functions manipulating data in the global environment.

Here is an example:

```
MakeData <- function(abrr = 'ASW',nfiles = 10){
  for(i in 1:nfiles){
  lst <- list(a = 1:10,
              b = rnorm(10)>0,
              c = sample(LETTERS,10))
  write.csv(lst,paste0("test_",abrr,i,".csv"))
  }
}

ImportData <- function(mypattern)
{
  temp <- list.files(".", pattern=mypattern)

  myfiles <- lapply(temp, read.csv) 
  names(myfiles) <- gsub("-.*", "", temp)
  myfiles
}

CombineData <- function(datalst,get = 'a')
{
  lst <- lapply(datalst, function(x) x[[get]])
  do.call(rbind, lst)
}

set.seed(314)
MakeData("ASW")
impdat <- ImportData("ASW")
CombineData(impdat,'b')
```

Which returns:

```
                [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
test_ASW1.csv  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
test_ASW10.csv FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
test_ASW2.csv   TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
test_ASW3.csv  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
test_ASW4.csv  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
test_ASW5.csv   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
test_ASW6.csv   TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
test_ASW7.csv   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
test_ASW8.csv  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
test_ASW9.csv  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or use `tidyverse` to load and process the data in a pipeline, like I prefer to do:

```
require(tidyverse)
data.frame(filename = list.files(".", pattern = "ASW"), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(lst = map(filename,~read.csv(.x)),
         dat = map(lst, ~as.data.frame(t(.x[['b']])))) %>%
  select(filename,dat) %>%
  unnest()
```