# Assign multiple array of vectors using for-loop and assign in R

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop

I was wondering which are the posibilities of vectorizing an array of vector using the `for-loop`.
The general idea is:

1. Vector names
2. Vector values
3. Assign each values from 2 in each 1

As and example
I've tried:

```
Names <- c('Arnold','Jhon' ,'Jim','Jason')`  
Surnames <- c('Palmer','Kramer' ,'Carrey','Momoa')`    
for (Name in Names){
    for (Surname in Surname){
      Name <- Surname
   }
}
```

What I'm expecting is to create multiple vector named from each individual value form the chracter string `Names` and each one of this new individual vectors assigned with each surname in `Surnames`. This would be like:

```
>Arnold
[1] "Palmer"
>Jhon
[1] "Kramer"
```

Definitely this isn't working, and I've been searching widebroad in the web, and although there are similar results, there is one that could be, with some modifications obviously, applied to my model. So if you know any other posted questions or any solution I'd be very gladly with you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output. Since R functions are already vectorized, you can just use `names(Surnames) <- Names` and `print(Surnames)`. No for-loop needed.

Comment: This is *not* a good way of thinking about variables and assigning them values in R. For example, what happens if you have two `Arnold`s? It's much better to store `Name` and `Surname` in some form of data structure, e.g. a `list` or a `data.frame`. Extracting entries then comes down to filtering & selecting relevant entries (e.g. through `match`ing entries, or joining with information from another `data.frame`). [Don't use `assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad), as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I only have non repeated values in vector `names` so `assign` function is going to work just fine, but I'll have what you are suggesting in mind in the future if some of my values are repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you had problems in your loop- I edited so you are looping through a numeric vector.  Plus I think the function you were looking for was `assign`

```
Names <- c('Arnold','Jhon' ,'Jim','Jason')
Surnames <- c('Palmer','Kramer' ,'Carrey','Momoa')
for( i in 1:length( Names) ){

      assign( Names[i] , Surnames[i] )

}

Arnold
```

Comment: Perfect that was what I need it, thank you a lot, I'll edit the question and marked as solved it.

Comment: @PauloCecco Please read [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad); this is *not* what you should be doing.

Comment: @MauritsEvers is right, this isn't the safest programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data.frame and then use the **attach()** function

```
Names <- c('Arnold','Jhon' ,'Jim','Jason')  
Surnames <- c('Palmer','Kramer' ,'Carrey','Momoa')

MyData <- rep(0,length(Names))
dim(MyData) <- c(1,length(Names))
MyData <- as.data.frame(MyData)

names(MyData) <- Names
MyData[1,] <- Surnames

attach(MyData) #This is the key
Arnold
Jhon
Jim
Jason
```