# How to modify a dataframe that can't be called directly?

Tags: r

I'm creating a function to that several data frames automatically. How can I call those data.frames to mutate them?

For example, say I created a data for which each item is meant to become a dataframe like so:

```
assign(paste0("d","f"),c(tree,fox,river))
```

Then I take an item from the list and use it to name a dataframe.

```
assign(paste(get(paste0("d","f"))[1]),as.data.frame(c(1,2,3))
```

so that now if i do:

```
get(paste(get(paste0("d","f"))[1]))
```

it returns a data frame with 1,2,3

**Here's my problem, I want to be able to modify those items so something like**

```
get(paste(get(paste0("d","f"))[1]))[1] <- 4

#So that now if i do

get(paste(get(paste0("d","f"))[1]))
```

it returns a data frame with 4,2,3

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish in the bigger picture? This feels like an [`XY Problem`](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: I strongly suggest you re-write your code not to depend on [get/assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad). Typically just using named lists will save you a lot of code/effort.

Comment: The bigger picture is that I have an excel sheet with multiple sheets and I am trying create a function that automatically imports each sheet as a separate data.frame and renames them based on the sheet name, add a column specifying which sheet a row came from, and then merges all those dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

It is better not  to create multiple objects in the global environment.  If it is already created, load them into a `list` and do all the changes/transformations/mutates etc. in the `list`.  It would make easier to read/write in `list` rather than looking for these objects floating in the global env

```
lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), function(x) {x[[1]] <- 4; x})
```

Comment: I think that did it. Thank you!