# cbind with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, cbind

I'm new with R and I've an issue
So my issue is :
I've multiples tables ex: 10 , also different list from kmeans results related to this tables (10). So I want use cbind in order to add each cluster  to its table :

Ex:

```
NEW_table1<- cbind(table1,kmeans_table1$cluster)
NEW_table2<- cbind(table2,kmeans_table2$cluster)
```

...

I've tryd with this code but a get an error

```
for (i in 1:10)
{ assign(paste0("NEW_table", i)<-cbind(as.name(paste0("filter_table",i)),Class=(i$cluster) )) 
}

> Error in i$cluster : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: `i` is an ìnteger index. `i$cluster` does not exist. And `assign` syntax is incorrect, second argument is `value` to store. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data I'll have a guess that this might work:

```
do.call(cbind, mapply(function(x, y) cbind(x, y), tables, kmeans, simplify=F))
```

where tables is a list of your tables i.e. list(tables)
and kmeans is a list of your kmeans i.e. list(kmeans)

```
x = 1:10
x2 = list(x, x, x)

y = 10:1
y2 = list(y, y, y)

do.call(cbind, mapply(function(x, y) cbind(x, y), x2, y2, SIMPLIFY = F))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want might be something like below

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(paste0("table",1:10), function(v) cbind(get(v),get(paste0("kmeans_",v))$cluster)),
                  paste0("NEW_table",1:10)),
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, I'v fixed by the following code:

```
# VAR its a list of distinct values from column in large table
VAR<- unique(table$column)

for(i in VAR){
  assign( 

    paste0("New_table", i),cbind(get(paste0("filter_table",i)),Class=get(i)$cluster)
    )
}
```