# R building simple function with for loop, returns nothing

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, cryptography, assign

I have a new R package here called "crypto" to collect coin prices, I'm using it to build a simple function to source in the future, the main idea is the following:

```
CryptoList <- c('BTC','ETH', .....)

for (i in 1: length(CryptoList))
{
  x = CryptoList[i]
  a = crypto_history(x, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
  assign (as.character(x), a)
}
```

It works out perfectly like this, however, when I built this into a function, it does not assign anymore.

```
getCryptoPrice <- function(CryptoList, start_date, end_date)
{
for (i in 1: length(CryptoList))`enter code here`
{
  x = CryptoList[i]
  a = crypto_history(x, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
  assign (as.character(x), a)
}
```

}

```
getCryptoPrice(CryptoList, '20180101', '20181231')

> BTC
Error: object 'BTC' not found
```

It looks like the assign function is not working properly, while it will if it's not in the function. Does anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use `assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad). Use `return` to return an object from the function. Or have the last object returned implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `for` loop and `assign` another way would be to return a named list. Lists are easier to manage and avoids polluting the global environment with lot of objects.

```
getCryptoPrice <- function(CryptoList, start_date, end_date) {
    output <- lapply(CryptoList, crypto::crypto_history, 
                    start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
    names(output) <- CryptoList
    return(output)
}
```

and then call it like :

```
output <- getCryptoPrice(CryptoList, '20180101', '20181231')
```

Now, you could access individual dataframes like `output[['BTC']]`, `output[['ETH']]` etc.