# Is there a way in R to store each iteration of a loop into a separate variable?

Tags: r, loops, tibble, storing-data

I am trying to store some descriptive tibbles into separate variables. More specifically, I am summarizing data into tibbles that delineate a list of countries and the population for each country for a certain year (1987-2016). Each iteration represents a year. My current repeat loop (see below) works great, but I'd like to be able to store each iteration into a separate variable so I can later combine those variables into a descriptive visual.

```
x = 1987
repeat {
  print(subset(data, year == x) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarize(sum(population)))
    x = x + 1
    if (x > 2016) {
    break
    }
  }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why not group by `year` and `country`?

Comment: `aggregate(population ~ year + country, data=data, FUN=sum)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results in a list :

```
x = 1987
l <-list()
repeat {
  l[[as.character(x)]]<-print(subset(data, year == x) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarize(sum(population)))
    x = x + 1
    if (x > 2016) {
    break
    }
  }
l
```

Comment: This is something like `split()` plus `lapply()`.

Comment: @jogo, you're right, I just answered the question as asked, but could have improved the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `assign()` like this:

```
for (i in 1990:2000) {
  assign(paste0('year_', i, "_dat"), i)
}
```

Not sure if that is the best way to accomplish your larger task, but `assign()` will do what you want. Seems like `i` will be a dataframe in your case, which will work fine.

`assign()` creates a variable in the environment and takes a name and an object as arguments - perfect for your case. We can use `paste0()` to dynamically generate the variable name with something we are looping over and give it any object to assign to that name.

Comment: Thank you! However, what would you recommend the best way to accomplish my larger task? I'm relatively new to R, so I'd love any thoughts/advice!

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad