# r: Can't use get() to retrieve variable name in colnames()

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a code snippet that will allow others to copy and paste it with minimal changes. There is a variable name that will be different every time, so I would like the other users to be able to assign the variable name to a variable at the head and then I will reference that variable using get() or assign(). This variable will be a data frame. For instance:

```
name_of_frame <- "number_one"
# This is where they will name the variable

assign (name_of_frame, read.csv("....", header=FALSE))

new_variable <- get(name_of_frame) [2:nrow(get(name_of_frame)),]
```

These work fine. The one that doesn't is this:

```
colnames(get(name_of_frame)) <- new_vector
```

This throws the error: **Error in colnames(get(name_of_frame)) <- new_vector :
could not find function "get<-"**

If I substitute this it works fine:

```
colnames(number_one) <- new_vector
```

Why is this the only context where I can't use get(name of variable) to substitute for the variable?

Comment: why's `<=` in 1st line?

Comment: If you replace the `<=` with `<-` the code you posted works fine for me. The error message you quote does not seem to be consistent with the code that is just above - are you sure it's that error for exactly that function?

Comment: Generally using [get/assign is not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad). Often there are more R-like ways to do things. You cannot use special functions like `colnames<-` with the results from `get()` because you are not passing in the symbol to be updated. `get()` returns a data.frame. Its the same as calling `colnames(data.frame(x=1)) <- c("hello")` which doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I had to retype my code, but the original has <- and it still doesn't work. I'm puzzled why it works for @MoritzSchwarz?

Comment: It looks like this has been closed, I will try to re-ask in a clearer way.