# Store data frames with names that are stored in vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to load all files in folder and save as dataset but I got problems to assign data frame names

I got a vector named 'names' with all names of data frame that I want and 'file_directory' vector with all file path that I created with list.files() function.

The code I have tried in the for loop is:

```
names[i] <- read_sas(file_directory[i])
```

when I do that it stores the data in i^th element of vector instead of assigning it as name to data frame.
How to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `assign`. In the `for` loop do :

```
assign(names([i]), read_sas(file_directory[i]))
```

But you should read [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) and what you should use instead [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames)