# Assign quanteda docvars programmatically with the function get()

Tags: r, quanteda

I am developing a routine to automatically define several corpora in **quanteda**. I have several parameters controlling the script and one of them is the name of the corpus that will be generated. I can easily create a corpus programmatically with the function `assign()` but I completely fail to add any *docvars* to it.

Once I define the corpus, I usually invoke it throughout the code with the function `get()`. I have been using this approach quite extensively with success. For some reason, the function `docvars()` does not seem to accept an object invoked with `get()`.

Please, have a look at the simple code below where I define the corpus and then try to associate a docvar to it.

```r
library(quanteda)
#> Package version: 2.1.2
#> Parallel computing: 2 of 16 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'quanteda'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     View

nameofthecorpus = "mycorpus"
mytext <- c( "This is a long speech made in 2020",
             "This is another long speech made in 2021")
thedocvars <- c( "2020", "2021" )

assign( nameofthecorpus, corpus( mytext ) )

# I can have a summary of the corpus with get()
summary( get( nameofthecorpus )  )
#> Corpus consisting of 2 documents, showing 2 documents:
#> 
#>   Text Types Tokens Sentences
#>  text1     8      8         1
#>  text2     8      8         1

# Now I wand to add some docvars automatically
# This is where I get stuck
docvars( get( nameofthecorpus ), "year" ) <- thedocvars 
#> Error in docvars(get(nameofthecorpus), "year") <- thedocvars: could not find function "get<-"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

In principle, I would like to generalize this to multiple docvars at once (e.g., like when they are stored in a data.frame).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would very strongly suggest you [avoid `get` and `assign` when possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) for manipulating variables like this. It's a very indirect approach and as you've already seen easily breaks when trying to use these indirect values to update values. When you run something like

```
docvars( mycorpus, "year" ) <- thedocvars
```

You are running a special function called `docvars<-` that returns a new object that will replace the value stored in `mycorpus`. When you put `get( nameofthecorpus )`, that's not a variable value that can be replaced, that's a function call that returns a value. So if you need to use `get/assign`, you'd have to do something like this

```
assign(nameofthecorpus, `docvars<-`(get( nameofthecorpus ), "year", thedocvars))
```

Were you retrieve the value from the name, explicitly call the transformational version of the `docvars` function to get an updated object value, and then reassign that value to the original variable name.

A better approach to `get/assign` is usually a named list. Something like

```
nameofthecorpus = "mycorpus"
mytext <- c( "This is a long speech made in 2020",
             "This is another long speech made in 2021")
thedocvars <- c( "2020", "2021" )

mydata <- list()
mydata[[nameofthecorpus]] <- corpus( mytext )
summary( mydata[[nameofthecorpus]]  )
docvars( mydata[[nameofthecorpus]], "year" ) <- thedocvars
```

Comment: Thank you! So there is no direct way to programmatically create an object and retain the correct class. I mean, I'd like a `corpus` object at the end of the script.

Comment: One additional point. doing `save( mydata[[ nameofthecorpus ]], file = "thepathtofile.RData" )` does not work with `object "mydata[[ nameofthecorpus ]]" not found`. How do I save an object defined in a list?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you are asking. I’m unclear how you are consuming this “script”. Perhaps this could all be avoided by just writing proper functions that return the final desired object rather than injecting it into an environment as a side effect.

Comment: If you are trying to save a single object, `saveRDS` would be a better choice. Then you don’t have to hard code a variable name at all.

Comment: I am using standard functions defined in **quanteda**. The only difference is that I want to be able to pass names dynamically. What you suggested worked out great. I can access the object of the wanted class no problem except when I want to save them (pls see comment above). All in all, I don't want to interact with the script. This is launched via `Rscript` or via Jobs in RStudio. Thank you

Comment: For the record, using `saveRDS()` works. I will change the way I load in data accordingly. Thanks!