# Opening dataframe in R from it's name

Tags: r, dataframe

I load all `.csv` files from a given folder and store all the names in the `filenames` variable.

```
# Loading files
filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$", "", list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"))

# Reading files
for(i in filenames)
  {
    assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep = ""), sep = ","))
  }
```

Now I'd like to access any dataframe with name that is in `filenames`. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call an object with the character variable of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083907/how-to-call-an-object-with-the-character-variable-of-the-same-name) You can use `get(i)` within the loop or just pass the specific string.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using the function `get()` as this can have bad consequences. I'd suggest using a more structured approach by mean of a list containing all you csv files. I don't have any data here so I will build upon your code.

```r
# Loading files
filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$", "", list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"))

# create a list with NULL
file_list = vector("list", length(filenames))

# name each element according to filenames
names(file_list) = filenames

# Loop over the list
# Please note that the iterator "i" now loops over the elements
# and does not take the real values in filenames

for (i in seq_along(file_list)) {
  current_file = read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))
  file_list[[ i ]] = current_file
}
```

Now you can access each element either with the standard indexing (`[[`) or via the names with the `$` operator.

#### UPDATE

For an example about why you should avoid `get()`, please refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248742/assign-quanteda-docvars-programmatically-with-the-function-get).

Comment: And if you still *really* want each file as it's own dataframe object in the environment, you can always use `list2env(file_list)` later. Either way, this should be the approach to read, not using `assign()`.