# An if statement returns a different variable on each branch, how can I sub-assign to that variable using only one <- operator?

Tags: r, if-statement, variable-assignment

Consider

```
a <- b <- 1:3
if(sample(2, 1) == 1) a[2] <- 5 else b[2] <- 5
```

This is repetitive. I would not like to have to write `<- 5` twice. It would be ideal to use

```
a <- b <- 1:3
assign(if(sample(2, 1) == 1) "a[2]" else "b[2]", 5)
```

but `assign` is no good for sub-assignment. What idiomatic alternatives exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idiomatic way to do it is not to have two variables, let them be entries in a list:

```r
l <- list()
l$a <- l$b <- 1:3
var <- sample(c("a", "b"), 1)
l[[var]][2] <- 5
l
#> $b
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1 5 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You could get something closer to what you were asking for by fooling around with environments:

```r
a <- b <- 1:3
var <- sample(c("a", "b"), 1)
e <- environment()
e[[var]][2] <- 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

but I wouldn't call this idiomatic.

Comment: Indeed. Related reading: [Why is using assign bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad); [FAQ 7.21](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f) ("At least in the first two cases it is often easier to just use a list"); `fortune(236)`; `fortune(106)`; `fortune(181)`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an idiomatic way to do this, but it is certainly possible to do it with a single assignment:

```r
a <- b <- 1:3
s <- if(sample(2, 1) == 1) "a" else "b"
assign(s, `[<-`(get(s), 2, 5))

a
#> [1] 1 2 3

b
#> [1] 1 5 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `eval(parse())` approach.

```
eval(parse(text=paste(c('a', 'b')[(sample(2, 1) == 1) + 1], '[2] <- 2')))
```

Or short:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(sample(c('a', 'b'), 1), '[2] <- 2')))
```