# name one variable according to another variable in R

Tags: r, variables, naming

I would like to name one variable according to another variable.

E.g.

```
a <- c(0.1,0.2)

for (i in a){

b(i) <- 1
}}
```

What I would like as outcome is

```
head(b0.1)
1
 
head(b0.2)
1
```

Comment: Notice that the expression `b(i)` implies to the R interpreter that `b` is the name of a function. The paired parentheses are not used for indexing in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `setNames`, then use `list2env` to save each variable to the global environment.

```
list2env(lapply(setNames(a, paste0("b", a)), function(x)
  x <- 1), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Another option is to use `paste` and `assign` from base R:

```
a <- c(0.1,0.2)

for(i in a) {
  nam <- paste0("b", i)
  assign(nam, 1)
}
```

**Output**

```
head(b0.1)
# [1] 1

head(b0.2)
# [1] 1
```

But generally using `assign` is not a good idea, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad).

Comment: You should also be giving this new useR advice about why this answer to an obvious duplicate is generally a bad strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need a loop here, What about:

```
paste0("b", a/10)

[1] "b0.01" "b0.02"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_c("b", a/10)
```