# How to automate to split a vector in single element named scalars

Tags: r, vector, assign

Background: Try to automate some process within a custom function. For this I need to know:

How can I assign each element in a vector to a new single named element:

```
x <- c(19L, 8L, 9L, 18L)

[1] 19  8  9 18
```

desired_output:

```
n1 <- 19
n2 <- 8
n3 <- 9 
n4 <- 18

> n1
[1] 19
> n2
[1] 8
> n3
[1] 9
> n4
[1] 18
```

I have tried:

```
z <- setNames(x, paste0("n", 1:length(x)))

n1 n2 n3 n4 
19  8  9 18
```

Comment: `for(n in 1:4) assign(paste0("n", n), x[n])`

Comment: @AdamQuek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%=%` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
paste0('n', seq_along(x)) %=% x
```

-output

```
> n1
[1] 19
> n2
[1] 8
> n3
[1] 9
> n4
[1] 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe first turn the vector into a list, then use `list2env`.

```
list2env(setNames(sapply(x, list), paste0("n", seq_along(x))), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I have to consider something special using list2env in functions embedded in Rmarkdown?

Comment: @TarJae I’m not sure how environment works in Rmarkdown  :(