# Is there a better way to reference datasets by name within a list in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop through several data frames that I import and convert all the variables to lowercase. I currently do it this way (I have about 20 data frames in my actual code):

```
datasets <- c("iris", "mtcars")

for (i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  df <- as.data.frame(get(datasets[i]))
  colnames(df) <- tolower(colnames(df))
  assign(paste0(datasets[i]), df)
}
```

I've previously read that using `get` and `assign` are not best practice so I was wondering how I could do this differently.

Comment: Perhaps `list2env(lapply(mget(datasets), \(x) setNames(x, tolower(names(x))), .GlobalEnv)` (recommend to keep it in a `list` instead of creating multiple objects in the global env)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17559390/6574038