# R for loop to filter dataframe into new dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working on some data contained in a dataframe (US) which has diagnosis rates (rate) for US states (location_name) for years 2000-2019 (year). I would like to separate this out into separate dataframes based on year.

I know I could do this manually by assigning `US_2000 <- US %>% filter(year == 2000)` but I was hoping to be able to produce a for loop to do this for all 20 years.
I have tried:

```
years <- distinct(US, year)

for (y in years) {
  name <- paste("US", as.character(y), sep="_")  
  name <- US %>% filter(year == y)
}
```

but this only seemed to produce one dataframe with name US_2000 and with a variety rows of different years (2-3 states per year).
The purpose of creating new dataframes is to use in a plotting function to produce visualisations of rates per state.
I'm very new to R and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to append each dataframe to a list with what you are trying to achieve

```
years <- distinct(US, year)
list1 <- list()

for (y in years) { 
  name <- US %>% filter(year == y)

  list1[[length(list1)+1]] = name
}

list1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not work, it will first put the string you are pasting into the object `name` and then replace the contents of `name` with a dataframe.  A better way is to create a list either using stefan's example or

```
mylist <- US %>%
           split(.$year)
```

that would also be easier to use for plotting since you can do something like

```
mylist %>% 
    lapply(function(x) plot(x))
```

to plot your individual tables.

For completeness: It is bad practice, but you can do what you want using

```
assign(paste("US",
          as.character(y), 
          sep="_"),
       US %>% filter(year == y))
```

inside your loop.

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest why is the assign() function bad practice? I tried it prior to posting but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It is appealing to use assign, but it is often not the way R works, usually having a list or other single object will be much easier down the road (see `lapply()` above). There are several discussions about this topic on SO, e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad